# What does the * mean in my css?

Tags: html, css

Does the * indicate that its styling will apply to all my other tags?

```
  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    outline:none;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#fff;
    background: transparent;
    border:none;
  }
```

Comment: answer is: yes :)

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors. Result No. 2 when googling "css star selector": https://www.google.de/search?ei=P5NLWvPvOcmtkwWQiJW4Cw&q=css+star+selector&oq=css+star+selector&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l3.8843.10258.0.10433.9.9.0.0.0.0.112.636.8j1.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.9.633...0i67k1j0i10k1.0.M_55Z9HjimA&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0 Next time you ask a question, please consider doing a minimal research effort yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: it indicates a css style that will apply to every single element in your page